# phpseclib - Disable SSH timeout

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I use phpseclib to make SSH connections and execute code. However it has a problem. A 13 second timeout. Anyway I could disable this timeout or make it longer? I need to download files on the server, which may be big so it would take more than 13 seconds

Comment: How do you know it is 13 seconds?

Answer (score 3):

Try `$ssh->setTimeout(100)`. Doing `$ssh->setTimeout(0)` will disable the timeout all together.